# Adding custom response Headers to APIException

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have created a custom exception referring to http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions.html.

Please know that I have my own authentication backend. Hence I am not using rest_framework's authentication module.

For authentication errors, I want to add 'WWW-Authenticate: Token' header to the response that is sent from the exception.

Any ideas will be very helpful.

Update:

Thanks @Pathétique,
This is what I ended up doing.

-Have a base view class named BaseView.

-override the handle_exception method to set appropriate headers, in my case 'WWW-Authenticate'.

Here is the code:

```
class BaseView(APIView):
  def handle_exception(self, exc):
     if isinstance(exc, MYEXCEPTION):
        self.headers['WWW-Authenticate'] = "Token"
        return Response({'detail': exc.detail,
                        status=exc.status_code, exception=True)
```

Your thoughts?

Comment: Encountered same issue and your suggestion worked as it should ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try overriding `finalize_response` in your rest framework view:

```
def finalize_response(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = super(SomeAPIView, self).finalize_response(request, *args, **kwargs)
    response['WWW-Authenticate'] = 'Token'
    return response
```

Edit:

After seeing your update, I think your override of `handle_exception` should work, I would only add an else statement to call the parent method to cover other exceptions. One thing I noticed in overriding dispatch, which may not be an issue here, is that setting a new key/value for self.headers resulted in a server error that I didn't take the time to track down. Anyways, it seems you are on the right track.

Comment: Thanks Pathétique, Please have a look at the updated question. 
What do you think?

Comment: Ahh, sorry I missed the significance of your custom Exception...will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `authenticate_header` method on your authentication class.

Additionally that'll ensure your responses also have the right `401 Unauthorized` status code set, instead of `403 Forbidden`.

See here: http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication.html#custom-authentication

Comment: Okay, I should've paid more attention to "I have my own authentication backend" :)

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is quite correct, in my case I found it more appropiate to add the header and then call the method on the super instance, to maintain default behaviour:

```
class BaseView(APIView):
  def handle_exception(self, exc):
     if isinstance(exc, MYEXCEPTION):
        self.headers['WWW-Authenticate'] = "Token"
        return super().handle_exception(excepto)
```